# How can I calculate table data that depends on other table data using only HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have the following:

```
<table id="tourney_stats" class="table table-hover tablesorter">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name <i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></th>
        <th>Wins <i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></th>
        <th>Losses <i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></th>
        <th>W/L Ratio <i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name 1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Name 2</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>0</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible to calculate the W/L Ratio column for all entries based on the table entry's Wins and Losses?

Basically I want the site to calculate 2/3 and put the result in the W/L Ratio column for Name 1, and 5/6 for Name 2 so that I don't have to do the calculation myself.

Thanks

Comment: NO. HTML is a presentation/layout description, it does not provide for expression evaluation.  However, with embedded Javascript this is trivial.

Comment: The point is if you are sending dynamic values for wins and losses(using a server side programming) you can do so for ratios as well.  And if your stats are static,  why don't you simply calculate and put those in the cells you want?!!  If static, why do you want to calculate this every time the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said "only HTML" but as @JimGarrison pointed out, this is fundamentally impossible. Seeing that your question is also tagged `javascript`...

```
var table = document.getElementById('tourney_stats');
var rows = table.rows;
for (var i = rows.length; i--;) {
    var row = rows[i].cells;
    row[2].textContent = row[0].textContent / row[1].textContent;
}
```

Will calculate the ratios on load-time.

Comment: My apologies.  I meant HTML and javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

you could calculate the w/l ratio using javascript and change the s textContent but i dont think its possible using only HTML since HTML is not a programming language

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer to show how JS can be used to do just that? Without that bit,  your answer tends to attract down votes because it is more of a comment than answer as of now.

Comment: to be honest i wasnt exactly sure how to do it without using ids or something but i saw that @rvighne came up with an efficient way to do it so i left out but youre right my answer was way too vague